# AngularJS style issue IE

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-scope, ng-style

Im trying to figure out how to make this work on IE:

`<div ng-if="result.is_mesurable==true" style="left:{{ (result.user_score * 20)-10}}%" class="test-box">`

The code basically generates a dynamic table, and the left position of the object is taken from the user_score value.

I know that IE doesn't read this declaration properly, i had a similar bug in the past:

[AngularJS weird render issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417900/angularjs-weird-render-issue)

*"Because {{xxx.xxx}} is invalid css it is trucated by IE and when the angular compiler scans all attributes, the style attribute is empty."*

I know there must be a similar solution, but so far i've been unable to figure it out.

Thx in advance.

also, just to note, the result on IE is an empty style attr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the same, solvable with ng-style or ng-attr-style:

ng-style:

```
<div ng-style="{left: ((result.user_score * 20) - 10) + '%'}" class="test-box" ng-if="result.is_mesurable==true">
```

ng-attr-*

```
<div ng-attr-style="left:{{ (result.user_score * 20)-10}}%" class="test-box" ng-if="result.is_mesurable==true" >
```

Comment: Great, thx again. I still find it very tricky to figure out angular + IE issues like this one.